# Play youtube video on hover

Tags: jquery, youtube

I just need to play the youtube video only when hovered

I have here a fiddle and can't get it to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function() {

      var playersrc = jQuery(iframe).attr('src');

          $('div').hover(function(){
          $('iframe').attr('src',playersrc+'&autoplay=1');
      }, function(){
          $('iframe').attr('src',playersrc);
      });
  });       
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rhr5p0pg/2/

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rhr5p0pg/4/

now it plays all and when your mouse leaves the it does not go back to its originial video

Comment: jquery is missing! (click on Javascript settings)

Comment: sorry, forgot that, modified my fiddle

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/rhr5p0pg/3/

Comment: you had 2 jquery ready

Comment: i got it working here but when mouse out it does not change to its original video https://jsfiddle.net/rhr5p0pg/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store just the first video uri (src).

What about something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var nowPlaying = "none";
      $('div').hover(function(){
          nowPlaying = $(this).find('iframe').attr('src');
          $(this).find('iframe').attr('src',nowPlaying+'&autoplay=1');
      }, function(){
          $(this).find('iframe').attr('src',nowPlaying);
      });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rhr5p0pg/5/

Comment: by the way @less how can I get rid of the white space under the video?

Comment: I played around a little  with the iframe css see https://jsfiddle.net/rhr5p0pg/8/

Comment: Please add &mute=1 in iframe url parameters.
It will perfectly work on hover Autoplay.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the video using Iframe Youtube Api, follow the examples [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=es-419).

Initialize your player and the use this Jquery code:

```
//Hover play
$('iframe').on('mouseover',function(){
    player.playVideo();
});

//Blur Pause

$('iframe').on('mouseout',function(){
    player.playVideo();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use the Youtube video API.
With the API you have more controle over the videos.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the issue that on hover doesn't play it's because of the Autoplay policy was changed. You need to set mute to your video. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes