# Youtube video autoplay with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to make a website with Youtube video iframes, which starts to play on hover.
I've found this post [Play youtube video on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302076/play-youtube-video-on-hover)

This code works(video start to play on hover) but not all videos work (links seem to be broken).
The same thing happens when I use other videos so that's not broken links. I've found a post suggesting changing 'iframe' into 'embed' and this fixed broken links but then script stops working.
My script looks like below:
https://codepen.io/EwelinaWoloszyn/pen/dybQGWe

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
      var nowPlaying = "none";

          $('div').hover(function(){
              nowPlaying = $(this).find('embed').attr('src');
                    $(this).find('embed').attr('src',nowPlaying+'&autoplay=1');
          }, function(){
              $(this).find('embed').attr('src',nowPlaying);
          });
});
```

What should I change to make it work?

Many thanks in advance,
Neko

Answer (score 0):

God forbid me for using W3Schools, but `video` elements in HTML5 have `play()` function in JavaScript

Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp

Your code:

```
      $('div').hover(() => {
                $(this).find('embed').play();
      });
```

Comment: Hey @Altair312 sorry I'm a beginner in JS. Should the code look like:

[link](https://codepen.io/EwelinaWoloszyn/pen/dybQGWe)

Comment: Okay, this was my mistake, it turns out you use embed for YouTube videos. They cannot be directly manipulated through JS/jQuery and should use YouTube API. 

Documentation here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference